# Implementing scrum-but for first time: how to deal with technical pre-requisites?

Tags: agile, scrum

After working Scrum(ish) in a previous workplace, I am trying to implement it in my new place of work for a brand new project (I am no scrum expert).  We have some pre-requisites to code before we can begin working on the stories (which are being groomed in the mean time).  Things like database design, api design, etc.  We plan to use two week iterations and it's just not clear to me how the first one (or two) can provide something useful to the customer and "potentially shippable" if we first have to "lay down some groundwork" ?  Any ideas on how to treat this?

Comment: http://www.pmscrum.com/blog/2011/06/10-things-do-sprint-0

Comment: better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: indeed it is - posted it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is very typical of new teams wanting to move to Scrum where they are coming from more of a traditional process.  Adapting to Scrum is very, very hard and we always say this, and the reason for this is there needs to be many mindset changes.

The first change the team should understand is that when bringing a PBI (requirement) into a Sprint, it only a well defined requirement with nothing else.  This means there is no designs, database schemas or API's for the requirement.  The team has to do all of this in the sprint, plus build and test the requirement.

If you are new to Scrum, you most probably are squirming in your seat thinking it cannot be done.  You are likely right for now, but this is where the hard work comes in ... changing the way teams work.  This is hard.

Some pointers :-

**Small Requirements** - Most teams suffer from poor, ambiguous requirements which previously took days to design, build and test.  The art is to learn to  break these *EPIC* requirements down into smaller incremental requirements where each one builds upon the previous, but explicitly adds business value.  Now, I am going to be blunt here ... this is the biggest challenge for most teams.   Personally, I have been training/coaching Scrum for a number of years now have not found any feature that cannot be broken down into small requirements with an average estimate of 2-3 days to fully complete.

**Team composition** - The team needs people in it with all the skills necessary to design, build and test the PBI.  They should not have dependencies on other people outside of the team.  Having dependencies, cripples teams but it highlights to management there are not enough people with the specialised skills.

**Sprint Planning** - Sprint planning should be used to do high level designs and discuss how the team is going to tackle delivering each requirement.   Many teams waste their sprint planning by clarifying weak requirements and debating the requirement.  This is a sign of weak requirements and it should be addressed.  Sprint planning is about discussing **How** to build/test a PBI and **not What**.

**Coach** - I would really recommend you hire an experienced contract coach/consultant to get you going and do things right.  Trying to do this by yourself, just leads to a world of unnecessary pain.

**Architecture** - At the inception of the project, there is nothing wrong for the team and architects to spend a day or two brainstorming the macro architecture of the product and discussing the technologies to be used.  However, when it comes to new requirements they are designed and adjusted into the product.  This sounds hard, but with the correct software engineering patterns using SOLID principles, well defined patterns as well as strong Continuous Integration and Unit Testing.  The risks of a bad architecture are eliminated.  There is not question that the team should have a member in it that has the skills to design an architect the new requirements.  [There is lots of evidence on the web that an evolving architecture with re-factoring results in a better application than a big upfront architecture - but that another debate]

**Application Lifecycle Management**  - Invest in strong ALM tooling with CI, unit testing, test lab, continuous deployment.  Having the right tools for the team allows you to deliver quickly, and a lack of these totally cripples you.  CI with automated testing is essential for an incremental product as there is fast and constant change and you want to protect that a change does not break a previous requirement.

**ScrumBut** - Ken and Jeff no longer support the use of the term ScrumBut as it is perceived as elitism and often comes across as belittling.  Instead it is preferred that teams are on the journey to implementing Scrum and helping them through coaching.

Welcome to your journey into Scrum, hang in there as it is very hard initially. Once you fully "get it", then you and your company will be really happy that you did.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world, Technical pre-requisites should be factored into the estimate of each story and you should only implement "just enough" to complete the story. See  "[Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work](http://xp.c2.com/DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork.html)"

Why do you need to design the API or the Database? Try to avoid [Big Up front design](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BigDesignUpFront). Avoid building Frameworks up front, apply [YAGNI](http://xp.c2.com/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html)

It's hard for you to understand how you could ship something in two weeks because you have the cart before the horse; that is, your priorities are wrong. The important thing is delivering customer software - not building databases or API designs.

This is a trade of against long term productivity and you should avoid accruing too much [technical debt](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html). Many Agile methodologies would argue that up-front work like this will be wrong and therefore should be avoided to minimise waste. Lean software recommends defering decisions to the [Last Responsible Moment](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/10/the-last-responsible-moment.html).